# Integration of $p\over {(1+p^2) \sqrt{1+p^2}}$

Tags: integration

Find

$\int {p\over {(1+p^2) \sqrt{1+p^2}}} dp$

My try

Let $u=1+p^2$

Then $p=\sqrt{u-1}$

And $dp={1\over {2\sqrt{u-1}}} du $

So

$\int {p\over {(1+p^2) \sqrt{1+p^2}}} dp={1\over 2}\int {u}^{-3\over 2} du$

$=-u^{-1\over 2}+c$

$=-{(1+p^2)}^{-1\over 2}+c$

$={-1\over {\sqrt{1+p^2}}}+c$

True?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything is correct.

Comment: Do not forget to add the $du$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks, I added it.